# Debug an .xml file that contains JavaScript and XML

Tags: javascript, xml, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to find some sort of IDE that will let me debug an .xml file that has XML and JavaScript in it. Every IDE that I tried only lets me debug XML but not the JavaScript, it will not read the script tags.

Comment: have you tried xmlspy? Back in the day, that was the primo xml editor.

Comment: Perhaps this? http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=simple&xsltfile=simple